# Encode image in base64 format and store in mysql database , not woring for all type of images with php and laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have upload one image and want to store it in base64 encoded format in database. for some images it is not working to store in database.

In my local system it is working for all images but on live server it not stores some of images in base64 format in mysql database . my code to store image in database is below,

```
$handle = $_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"];
 $fileObj = $req->files->get('file_name');
 $filename = $fileObj->getClientOriginalName();
 $fileInfo = pathinfo($filename);
 $fileExt = $fileInfo['extension'];
 $file1 = $req->files->get('file_name');
 $mime = $file1->getMimeType();
 $fileName = base64_encode(file_get_contents($handle));

$File = new File();
$File->file_name = $fileName;
$File->save();
```

from above code if I chane below line then it is working

$fileName = (file_get_contents($handle));

but I want to store it in base64 encoded format in mysql database

in my data table this field's type is "`long blob`".

Answer (score 1):

If you base64 the image, the column should be longtext. Blob are for binary.

But think again before storing files to database.

1. Storing image to database is a bad practice because whenever your app layer (in your case, php) retrieve the images, it will increase your memory usage and if you are retrieving list, your server can easily out of memory if multiple users are using the same function.
2. Storing data as base64 make it worse because the data size is bigger (8/6)

The best practice is to store the file in a file server and only the necessary meta or link in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Storing image details instead saving a blob is better. You can store all images on another server or the same server in a folder and store the path , name of that image in mysql. To retrieve it you can simple get the file from the path stored in mysql.